# Debian iptables load fail

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, debian-jessie

I Have Debian 8 Jessie and I have installed iptables, but it's not correctly. I can add rule just like: `iptables -A OUTPUT -s 212.50.128.0/19 -j DROP` but it's not working. `iptables -L` command works correctly. I tried reinstalling iptables but that did not help me.

`apt-get install iptables`

Status give me that message

`root@awakening:~# service iptables status
● iptables.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)`

I can't start or restart iptables correctly

`root@awakening:~# service iptables start
Failed to start iptables.service: Unit iptables.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`

Comment: Debian Jessie work diferent. Read this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209393/debian-8-update-iptables-on-boot